# applescript with loop stops (on Yosemite) when user interacts with application

Tags: applescript, infinite-loop

Forgive me if this turns out to be a dumb question, I've been writing cocoa apps for a long time but have only recently started to make them scriptable.

Scripting with this particular app is working well. But if the script has a loop like this...

```
tell application "myApplication"
  repeat
    set someProperty of someObject to someValue
    delay 0.5
  end repeat
end tell
```

(this is actually a script to cycle the colour of a connected bulb, so it does want to be an infinite loop.)

... no problem when everything's running on Mavericks. But on Yosemite, if the user interacts with myApplication's UI then things stop working. The script continues running (without things happening in myApplication) for a while before the script stops with a timeout (-1712)

The 'setter' for someProperty in the someObject class returns void and I've confirmed with messages to the console that it returns correctly every time it's called.

Is this behaviour expected? Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not a dumb question, I think this is a bug in the OS, as my app shows the same problem, which always worked in the past.

I was able to work around it by adding an idle timer that just looks for and handles apple events.  

Not a true solution, but a practical band-aid: I feel it is very inelegant to be resorting to a pull-event model, rather than relying on the existing (and previously working) push-event model.

Does anyone have any clue why apple events are not being handled when you browse the menus in the menu bar (or track any control) ??